# How the 4 more bytes for each characters are utilized

Tags: python-3.x

I experiment on the array

```
In [38]: arr = []                                                                                                                                     

In [39]: for k in range(10): 
    ...:     arr.append("s") 
    ...:     print(f"Length: {k:2d}, size: {sys.getsizeof(arr): 3d}") 
    ...:                                                                                                                                              
Length:  0, size:  96
Length:  1, size:  96
Length:  2, size:  96
Length:  3, size:  96
Length:  4, size:  128
Length:  5, size:  128
Length:  6, size:  128
Length:  7, size:  128
Length:  8, size:  192
Length:  9, size:  192
```

it could be concluded that, each character takes (128-96)/ 4 = 8 bytes.

As I know, python utilize unicode which take 4 bytes for each character.

Python's character has 4 more bytes.

Could you please provide any hints how the 4 more bytes are utilized?

Comment: You're using a 64 bit python.  The list just contains pointers to the strings, and those pointers are 64 bits long.

Comment: awesome, could you please transmit the comment to answer. @PatrickHaugh